# how to run insert statement in spark sql to insert timestamp column?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created below table create using spark sql and inserted value using spark.sql

```
create_table=""" create table tbl1 (tran int,count int) partitioned by (year string) """
spark.sql(create_table)
insert_query="insert into tbl1 partition(year='2022') values (101,500)"
spark.sql(insert_query)
```

But I want to insert values into timestamp column using spark sql

```
create_table="create table tbl2 (tran int,trandate timestamp) partitioned by (year string)"
spark.sql(create_table)
```

But below insert statement is not working and throws error

```
insert_query="insert into tbl2 partition(year='2022') values (101,to_timestamp('2019-06-13 13:22:30.521000000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'))"
spark.sql(insert_query)
```

how to insert timestamp value into table using spark sql. Please help

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: insert_query="insert into tbl2 partition(year='2022') values (101,to_timestamp('2019-06-13 13:22:30', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))"
spark.sql(insert_query)

I got AnalysisException: cannot evaluate expression to_timestamp('2019-06-13 13:22:30', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') in inline table definition; line 1 pos 52

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
create_table="create table tbl5 (tran int,trandate timestamp) partitioned by (year string)"
spark.sql(create_table)


insert_query="insert into tbl5 partition(year='2022') values (101,cast(date_format('2019-06-13 13:22:30.521000000', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') as timestamp))"
spark.sql(insert_query)
spark.sql("select * from tbl5").show(100,False)

+----+-----------------------+----+
|tran|trandate               |year|
+----+-----------------------+----+
|101 |2019-06-13 13:22:30.521|2022|
+----+-----------------------+----+
```